# Starting a song with this sentence

Tags: spoken-english

In a Bollywood film of srk a song start with this:[link](https://www.quotes.net/mquote/5617)

> The amalgamation before the fluctuation and ramification of the constitutional ambiguity and the judicial paradoxical position can be a verbal turmoil.

The setting of the song is a **casino.**

Searching these words in a dictionary make me more confused.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's just playing with language (whimsically creating "verbal turmoil"). If it makes you smile, fine. If not, just ignore it - there's no "meaning". Not even as much as might be contained in the word [***supercalifragilisticexpialidocious***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious).

Comment: I know nothing about the film, but i would guess that it's just a clever-sounding sentence that no-one is meant to understand.